# running gam command inside perl script

Tags: perl

Im new to perl and trying to run the below advanced gam command **within a simple perl script** but it will not print the output to screen no matter what I use - what am I doing wrong ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#exec ("ls -l");

chdir '/home/ted/bin/gamadv-xtd3';

#exec ("gam user ted.jones@co.com show contacts emailmatchpattern sarah.owens@co.com  fields email");
#system "gam user ted.jones@co.com show contacts emailmatchpattern sarah.owens@co.com  fields email";
exec ("gam user ted.jones@co.com show contacts emailmatchpattern sarah.owens@co.com fields email");
```

Comment: note that double quoted strings interpolate variables like `@co`. Try use single quotes instead

Comment: You could just use shell script/batch file, depending on your OS, and not complicate things by using Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code snippet demonstrates how you should use `system()` call in perl.

Please see: [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system), [Quote and Quote-like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd  = $ENV{HOME} . '/bin/gamadv-xtd3';
my @args = qw/gam user ted.jones@co.com show contacts emailmatchpattern sarah.owens@co.com fields email/;

system($cdm,@args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always begin your programs with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. This will catch and report many issues with your code.

For this particular code, it may just be that the interpolation of `@co` inside your string is failing (causing the `gam` command to fail). Or it may be that `gam` is not on your path and so the `exec` itself is failing.